# Issue with deleting a doc in firestore with react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am building a todo list application with expo/react native and have added a delete button for each looped todo. However, once you click it a type error of occurs:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_n9.indexOf')]

code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {useState} from "react"
import { SafeAreaView, Text, View, Button, TouchableOpacity, Modal, StyleSheet,Pressable, TextInput,ImageBackground, Image, ScrollView,  } from 'react-native';
import { collection, doc, setDoc, query, getDocs, onSnapshot, addDoc, orderBy, limit, Timestamp, where, deleteDoc} from "firebase/firestore"; 
import {db} from "../firebase"
import { auth } from '../firebase';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Checkbox from 'expo-checkbox';
import {signPlsOut} from "../firebase"
import { Appearance } from 'react-native';
import EmojiSelector from 'react-native-emoji-selector'

export  const Dashboard = () => {
  const image = { uri: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/901614276748402820/946157600041476176/Screen_Shot_2022-02-23_at_4.32.16_PM.png" };
  const {uid, photoURL, displayName, email} = auth.currentUser;
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState([]);
  const [modalVisibleImage, setModalVisibleImage] = useState([])
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const todosref = collection(db, 'todosref')
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const date = new Date().toLocaleString();
  const [emojiuser, setEmojiUser] = useState("")
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const onClick = emoji => {
        console.log(emoji);
    };
 
  const colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme();
  if (colorScheme === 'dark') {
    // Use dark color scheme
  }
  const [profilename, setProfileName] = useState("")
  const shadowColors = ["#FFD6A7", "#FF92B3", "#59F5D1", "#C1F1FE", "#A498FE"]
  const shadowColor = shadowColors[Math.floor(Math.random()*shadowColors.length)];
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const q = await query(todosref, where('uid', '==', uid), orderBy("createdAt"))
      onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        let todos = []
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {todos.push(doc.data())})
        setProjects(todos)
      })
    }
    getData()
  }, [])
  async function handleAddTask () {
    try {
      await addDoc(todosref, {
        title: title,
        desc: desc,
        createdAt: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
        uid: uid,
        backgroundColor: shadowColor,
        emoji: emojiuser,
        checked: false
      }) 
      setTitle("")
      setDesc("")
      setModalVisible(false)
      setEmojiUser("")
    }
    catch(error) {
      console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
      // ADD THIS THROW error
      throw error;
    }
  }
  const deleteDoc = async (id) => {
    try {
      const userDoc = doc(db, "todosref", id);
      deleteDoc(userDoc);
    } catch(error){
      alert(error)
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
    <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}
      visible={modalVisible}
    
      onRequestClose={() => {
        Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
        setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
      }}
  >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>Add task:</Text>
            <View style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
              <TextInput placeholder='title' value={title} onChangeText={(text) => setTitle(text)} style={{marginBottom: 20, fontSize: 20}}></TextInput>
              <TextInput placeholder='description' value={desc} onChangeText={(text) => setDesc(text)}></TextInput>
              
            </View>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: "700", fontSize: 20, marginBottom: 20}}>Emoji:</Text>
            <EmojiSelector onEmojiSelected={emoji => setEmojiUser(emoji)} showTabs={false} showSearchBar={false} columns="10" /> 
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
              onPress={handleAddTask}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>submit task</Text>
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.cancel]}
              onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
            >
              <Text style={{color: "#000", fontSize: 20}}>Cancel</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisibleImage}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>Change PFP</Text>
           <View style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between", marginBottom: 20}}>
           <Image source={{uri: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/926690547253534740/952329304056946758/Screen_Shot_2022-03-12_at_5.16.26_PM.png"}}style={{
              height: 60,
              width: 60,
              marginRight: 20,
              borderRadius: 40
            }}></Image>
            <Image source={{uri: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/926690547253534740/952329352421449828/Screen_Shot_2022-03-12_at_5.16.46_PM.png"}}style={{
              height: 60,
              width: 60,
              marginRight: 20,
              borderRadius: 40
            }}></Image>
            <Image source={{uri: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/926690547253534740/952329388077228052/Screen_Shot_2022-03-12_at_5.16.56_PM.png"}}style={{
              height: 60,
              width: 60,
              borderRadius: 40
            }}></Image>
           </View>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
              onPress={() => setModalVisibleImage(!modalVisibleImage)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Cancel</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <SafeAreaView style={{
      flex: 1,
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      margin: 20,
      flexDirection: "column", 
  }}>
     <View style={{
       flex: 1,
       marginTop: 20,
     }}>
        <View style={{marginBottom: 20, display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
          <View style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row"}}>
          <Pressable onPress={() => setModalVisibleImage(true)}>
      <Image source={{uri: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/856542608171073616/947245168191496212/Screen_Shot_2022-02-26_at_4.33.30_PM.png"}} style={{width: 50, height: 50}}></Image>
      </Pressable>
          <View style={{marginLeft: 20, display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
            <TextInput style={{fontSize: 17, fontWeight: "700"}}  placeholder={email} placeholderTextColor="#9D9EA2" />
            <Text style={{color: "grey", fontSize: 15}}>Good Day </Text>
          </View>
          </View>
          <View style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center"}}>
            <AntDesign name="search1" size={24} color="black" />
            <Feather name="bell" size={24} color="black" style={{marginLeft: 10}}/>
          </View>
       </View>
       <View  style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", marginBottom: 20, alignSelf: "center"}}
        ><Text style={{marginLeft: 30, fontSize: 27, fontWeight: "700", marginRight: 10}}>{new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
          weekday : 'long'
        })}</Text> 
          <Text style={{marginRight: 5, fontSize: 27, fontWeight: "700"}}> 
          {new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
          month : 'long'
        })},</Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 27, fontWeight: "700", marginRight: 30}}>{new Date().getDate()}th</Text>
      </View>
    <ScrollView style={{
      flex: 1, padding: 10, borderRadius: 20, marginBottom: 20, 
      backgroundColor: "#F5F4F7", position: "relative"
      }}>
         <Text style={{
           fontSize: 20,
           fontWeight: "700"
         }}>Goals for Today</Text>
        <View style={{display: "flex", flexDirection:  "column"}}>
        {projects.map((doc, key) => (
          <View key={key} style={{
            backgroundColor: doc.backgroundColor,
            padding: 20,
            marginTop: 20,  
             display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column", 
            justifyContent: "space-between", 
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 20,
            borderColor: 'transparent',
            borderBottomWidth: 0,
            shadowColor: doc.backgroundColor,
            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
            shadowOpacity: 1,
            shadowRadius: 20,
            elevation: 3,
            flex: 1, 
          }}>
            <View style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center"}}>
            <Text style={{}}>{doc.emoji}</Text>
            <Text style={{
            fontSize: 26, 
            color: "#fff",
            fontWeight: "700", 
            marginLeft: 10
          }}>{doc.title}</Text>
            </View>
          <View>
          <Text style={{
            fontSize: 18 , color: "#fff",marginLeft: 34

          }}>{doc.desc}</Text>
          </View>
          <View>
           <View>
             <Button title='Delete todo' onPress={(e) => deleteDoc(doc.id)}></Button>
             </View>
          </View>
          </View>
     ))}

        </View>
           <View style={{backgroundColor: "#4630EB", borderRadius: "20", padding: 10, alignSelf: "center", bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0, marginTop: 100}}>
      <Button title='Sign Out' onPress={signPlsOut}  color="#fff" style={{
                    color: "#fff" 
            }}></Button>
      </View>
       </ScrollView>
     </View>
     <View style={{
         display: "flex",
         alignItems: "center",
         justifyContent: "center",
         flexDirection: "row", 
         
       }}>
         <TouchableOpacity >
         <Pressable
        onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}>
           <AntDesign name="pluscircle" size={50} color="#8BF45B" />
        </Pressable>
         </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
      </>
      
  );
};
```

the main issue of the code is the

```
const deleteDoc = async (id) => {
    try {
      const userDoc = doc(db, "todosref", id);
      deleteDoc(userDoc);
    } catch(error){
      alert(error)
    }
  };
```

and

```
 <View>
           <View>
             <Button title='Delete todo' onPress={(e) => deleteDoc(doc.id)}></Button>
             </View>
          </View>
```

Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: I would try renaming deleteDoc function you have created, because it could have been referenced by your arrow function with the firebase one.
And try to log in console the ids, to be sure they are being passed when you click to delete a todo. 
And could you check if you don't need an await here? 
```await deleteDoc(userDoc);```

Answer (score 0):

You would get that kind of error if you are passing a value of `undefined` to your `userDoc` variable. On your `useEffect`:

```
    const getData = async () => {
      const q = await query(todosref, where('uid', '==', uid), orderBy("createdAt"))
      onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        let todos = []
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          // doc.data() doesn't have the document's ID by default.
          todos.push(doc.data())})
          setProjects(todos)
      })
    }
```

You're pushing the document's data to the `todos` array which does not include the document ID (unless you have an `ID` field on your document). You could instead use the `.map()` method to add the document ID and set it on the `projects` state. See code below:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const q = await query(todosref, where('uid', '==', uid), orderBy("createdAt"))
      onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        // Includes the document's ID.
        const documents = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
        setProjects(documents)
      })
    }
    getData()
  }, [])
```

Also, as pointed out by @guiwme5, for best practice, don't use the same name for your function as it will be recognized as a recursive function. I would suggest changing it to something like `deleteDocument`:

```
  const deleteDocument = async (id) => {
    try {
      const userDoc = doc(db, "todosref", id);
      deleteDoc(userDoc);
    } catch(error){
      alert(error)
    }
  };
```

View:

```
  <View>
    <Button title='Delete todo' onPress={(e) => deleteDocument(doc.id)}></Button>
  </View>
```

For more information, check out this documentation:

- [Delete documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#web-version-9)